# Android: Read and Write Primitive Types to Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-file, internal-storage

Is is possible to read and write primitive datatypes to/from a file in internal storage?

I've found plenty of tutorials and examples for using read(bytes[]) and similar functions, but nothing for reading and writing, for example, data members for a class, or a bunch of ints, doubles, and Strings. Relying on a function that blindly reads some number of bytes and then trying to parse the result with offsets and typecasting seems very non-Android to me, but I can't seem to find an alternative.

Perhaps I'm attempting to use the wrong tool for the wrong job and that's why I'm running into this roadblock. I'm writing an app that connects via BluetoothLE (using probably the worst API I've ever seen, but that's what the project requirements called for so I'm stuck with it), and after I connect to a device, I want to save the device's "name" which appears to be something akin to a MAC address but for Bluetooth, and the next time I see the device I want to display its "Friendly Name" which is a more human-readable name that I will know after connecting to the device for the first time. This lets me display the friendly name for a device that has been connected to before - and skip an authentication step. Is there, perhaps, a better mechanism than internal storage to store this kind of data? i.e. a few strings and an int.

Comment: The answers by Lamorak and SuNnY_sYeD are both workable approaches to what I wanted to accomplish, but they don't really answer the title question. I'll leave this open for a little while longer and see if a really good answer shows up.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods, read the [documantation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). For your case you could maybe use `SharedPreferences` or better create simple `SQLite` database.

Comment: I considered using SharedPreferences, but my understanding is that you need to use key-value pairs and can store only primitives. I may need to store several sets of name-friendly name-id "structs" for lack of a better term and would need to associate lists with each key. Can SharedPreferences handle that? I'll have to look in to the SQLite database and see if it's not overkill for my application.

Comment: Yes `SharedPreferences` can store only simple key-value pairs, what you described is definitely case for SQLite. Using it in android is not very hard, I wouldn't consider it overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences but convert your Object into a json object then store it into the SharedPreferences and reverse the process when you want to read the data back out.

Comment: This seems like the easy solution - I like easy don't get me wrong - but it feels like cheating. Are SharedPreferences meant to be used this way?